# python buildout 環境を作る際に、setuptools のバージョンを固定する方法

Tags: python, setuptools

Mac OS X, Python 2.7.6 を使用し、以下のように buildout 環境を構築しています。

```
$ python bootstrap.py
$ bin/buildout
```

この時に最新の `setuptools` がインストールされてしまい、現時点だと `12.0.4` がインストールされます。しかしこのバージョンには、以下のバグが存在し、この後行うインストールでバージョン依存の問題が出てしまいます。

[Issue #310 "document the backward-incompatible PEP 440 change to requirement semantics"](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/issue/310/document-the-backward-incompatible-pep-440)

`setuptools` を古いバージョン(例えば `8.0` とか)にすれば、問題が解決するのではないかと考えています。

以下で、 buildout のバージョンを固定する方法が見つけました。しかし、これだけでは `setuptools` のバージョンが固定されません。

```
$ python bootstrap.py -v VERSION
```

Comment: 最新のbootstrap.pyでは、 `--setuptools-version` ができるようになっているようです。
https://bootstrap.pypa.io/bootstrap-buildout.py
bootstrap.pyのバージョンアップなどを行ってみます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

最新のbootstrap-buildout.pyであれば `--setuptools-version=8.3` のように指定したら良いようですね。

```
$ virtualenv venv
$ cd venv
$ source bin/activate
(venv)$ curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/bootstrap-buildout.py
(venv)$ mkdir test
(venv)$ cd test
(venv)$ python bootstrap-buildout.py --setuptools-version=8.3 init sphinx
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-8.3.zip
Extracting in /tmp/tmpxqeprj
Now working in /tmp/tmpxqeprj/setuptools-8.3
Building a Setuptools egg in /tmp/tmp_woqs9
/tmp/tmp_woqs9/setuptools-8.3-py2.7.egg
Creating '/tmp/venv/test/buildout.cfg'.
Installing py.
Generated script '/tmp/venv/test/bin/sphinx-apidoc'.
Generated script '/tmp/venv/test/bin/sphinx-build'.
Generated script '/tmp/venv/test/bin/sphinx-quickstart'.
Generated script '/tmp/venv/test/bin/sphinx-autogen'.
Generated interpreter '/tmp/venv/test/bin/py'.
```

`--allow-site-packages` も併用すると、virtualenvにインストールされているsetuptoolsのバージョンが同じであればそれを使ってます。